# French diphthongs and dieresis

Tags: prononciation, orthographe

I would like to know the list of diphthongs and vowels with dieresis in French. Because I need the correct syllable division.

Comment: In general or for a specific word?  This might be too broad; can you contribute what research you've done so far to show us where you need help?

Comment: In general. French has a general rule.

Comment: There's [this chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_orthography#Vowels_and_combinations_of_vowel_letters) in Wikipedia? Does that help, or do you need something else?